# 3D rotation of a element in RaphaelJS

Tags: raphael

I am hoping you might be able to help me determine if the following animation is allowed in raphael.js. I am trying to have an element fly off the page, the idea is to have it appear to fall/fly off in 3D. I am able to tell the element to rotate X degrees and slide off but its lacking the look of the element being independent of hte background. What I would like to do is be able to tell raphael to rotate the top corner "out" as it falls giving the illusion of it falling out of view as picture falling off of a wall. Is this even possible or does Raphael only operate in two dimensional space?

Answer (score 0):

Raphael only deals with 2D space. To implement a 3D flip you have to fake it. Thankfully Raphael implements Scale(sx,sy,x,y) as a transform op, so you can scale about an origin to fake a 3D 'flip' rotation.

For example:

```
Raphael.el.flipXTransform = function (parentBbox) {
    var x = this.getBBox().x; 
    var width = this.getBBox().width;
    parentBbox = parentBbox || { width:width, x: x};
    var parentWidth = parentBbox.width;
    var parentX = parentBbox.x; 
    var originX = parentX - x + parentWidth / 2;
    return 's-1,1,' + originX + ',0';    
};

Raphael.el.flipX = function (duration, easing, parentBbox) {
    duration = duration || 500;
    easing = easing || 'easeInOut';
    var scale = this.flipXTransform(parentBbox);
    this.animate({ transform: '...' + scale }, duration, easing);   
};
```

Here's a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vQRv5/) for you to play with. The downside is this doesn't convey a perspective like a true 3D rotate does.